# Ajax loading image did not show before ajax content load; image and content load at the same div

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to load an image loader first in `<div id="ajax-content-container">` before a data content will be showed in the same div `<div id="ajax-content-container">` using ajax. However, the image loader did not even show up, the content showed directly without loading the image loader first. If I place return false under beforeSend, it shows reverse and the load didn't stop.

```
  beforeSend: function(){
  $('#ajax-content-container').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/img/ajax-
  loader.gif" width="200" height="200" style="margin-left:450px; margin-top:300px;" />');
    return false;
}`
```

How to get this done? Here are my codes. Thanks for the help.

View:

```
<?php if (!isset($ajax_req)): ?>
<div class="row">

 <div class="span3"> <?php echo
 form_dropdown('courses',$dropdown,$selected_value,'id="select_id"');?> </div>
 <div class="span3"> <?php echo 
 form_dropdown('schedule',$dropdown_sched,$date_value,'id="date_option"');?> </div>
 <div class="span2"> <?php echo 
 form_dropdown('status',$dropdown_status,$status_value,'id="status_id"');?></div>


 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>

<div id="ajax-content-container">

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Email Address</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Status</th>

</tr>
<?php foreach ($student_list as $key=>$value): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $value->first_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->last_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->email; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->phone_no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->status; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

 </table>
 </div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
ajax_courses();
ajax_sched();
ajax_status();

 });

function ajax_courses() {

$('#select_id').change(function () {
var course_id = $("#select_id").val();
var postData = {'course_id':course_id};
var timeout;

$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ajax_student_controller/get_ajax_course_student/",
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "html",
  beforeSend: function(){
  $('#ajax-content-container').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/img/ajax- 
  loader.gif" width="200" height="200" style="margin-left:450px; margin-top:300px;" 
  />');

  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#ajax-content-container').html(data);

  },

  })
  });

  }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this , you don't need to wrap a `change` function inside `ajax_courses()` just put it in ready and when `onchange` function is called the loader image will be added in the `ajax-content-container` and when `ajax` request is completed the `ajax-content-container` div will have the desired content in a container .

Note **Make sure Your loading image path is correct otherwise image will not be shown**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
//ajax_courses();
ajax_sched();
ajax_status();   

$('#select_id').change(function () {
$('#ajax-content-container').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>/img/ajax-loader.gif" width="200" height="200" style="margin-left:450px; margin-top:300px;" />');
var course_id = $("#select_id").val();
var postData = {'course_id':course_id};
var timeout;

$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/ajax_student_controller/get_ajax_course_student/",
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#ajax-content-container').html(data);    
  },3000); // 3 seconds delay

  },

  });//end ajax
  }); // end onchange

  });//end ready

 </script>
```

Other way i will recommend that place the loading image in the ajax-content-container div with `display:none` and when `onchange` happened use `$(".loading_image").show()` when `ajax` completed then if loading_image exists use `$(".loading_image").hide()`

Hope it helps you

Comment: Loading image is still not there. Maybe it works very fast. I checked the image path but its correct.

Comment: See my edited answer i have added `setTimeout` for 3 seconds if it is fast response but its not a good idea to use the `setTimeout` because after you make on live server if your requests takes 5 second to complete then again 3 second delay will be added , because many server are slow / fast depends on hosting

Comment: Is there anything I can use to show the loading image? I already tried using setTimeout,fadeOut,etc. Perhaps, I just placed it in a wrong way.

Comment: Other way i will recommend that place the loading image in the ajax-content-container div with `display:none` and when `onchange` happened use `$(".loading_image").show()` when `ajax` completed then `$(".loading_image").hide()`